Apocalypse manhwa where the main character dreams of zombies. Chains are used to fight
This was a manhwa in which the main character dreams about zombies and it comes real with a system.

He uses chains to fight,

Zombies have palm sized red gems used to upgrade things



Hi there, welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you [edit] in a few more details perhaps? When did you read this? Was it in colour or black-and-white? Can you recall any details about the MC?

Could this be All Rounder? The main character dreams of a zombie apocalypse. It comes real and he uses chains as weapons.

A world full of zombies. But this apocalypse… is it worth trying?!
[Skills can be ‘transferred’ from experts.] Mental care, wooden
construction, heavenly magic, animal communication, mechanical
engineering, performance, etc.. There is so much to learn! The sprint
of the prepared survivor, who is good at everything, begins!


